# Find tags by custom field value - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm customizing the admin of wordpress and I've created a new custom input field for the tags of a post. 
It's a dropdown list with all the categories of a post. Now, I wanna find all the tags with an specific category. So, I'm using this:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key'        => 'project',
    'meta_value'      => $idProject,
);

$allTags = get_tags( $args );
```

Is this the right way to get all the tags that I want? The problem is that the array list with the tags is coming with only one result. It should bring 2 tags with the project id that I'm passing on the variable $args.

Am I missing something?

**I found a solution:**

```
$args = array(
'hide_empty' => false, // also retrieve terms which are not used yet
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
       'key'       => 'project',
       'value'     => $idProject
    )
)
);
$terms = get_terms( 'post_tag', $args );
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Did you put any custom input field in the categories? Are you looking for categories or are you looking for post?

Comment: I edit the tags form inside the admin adding an input, a dropdown with all the categories of the posts. Now, inside a page, I wanna get all the tags that have this field with an specific value. Let's say I have 2 tags with this new field with the value of 1. How can I find these 2 tags searching by this new input field value?

Comment: Still not getting a picture about your setup. Can you take a screenshot at the "tags form" that you mentioned and paste here? Thanks.

Comment: Let me try again. Every post inside wordpress have a category and a tag right? But I added a new custom field on the tag. Above the description now there's a dropdown field, ok?  So. This field has a information that I wanna filter when I get all the tags of my wordpress site. It's a custom field, and I wanna get my tags cosidering the value on it. How do I do that?